# What is the difference between Non-harmonic oscillation, Anharmonic oscillation and Complex harmonic oscillation?

Tags: terminology, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, vibrations, anharmonic-oscillators

I am just wondering if the words Non-harmonic oscillation, Anharmonic oscillation and Complex harmonic oscillation mean the same thing. If not what exactly is the difference between them?

Since the post has generated no answer let me try to note down what I have understood so far: Oscillatory motion or vibratory motion is a type of periodic motion. HArmonic motion is a type of oscillatory motion in which there is a restoring force which is proportional to the displacement and the frequency and amplitude of the oscillation are independent of each other.

SHM is a type of Hamonic motion which has been idealized under the condition that there is no damping or there is any external excitation force(ie it is very simple to define mathematically). (Restoring force is directly proportional to the displacement the frequency and amplitude of the oscillation are independent of each other)

Complex Harmonic motion is a type of Harmonic motion in which the external exiting force and damping are considered(which makes it complicated than SHM).(Restoring force is directly proportional to the displacement the frequency and amplitude of the oscillation are independent of each other)

Anharmonic motion and non-harmonic motion means the same thing under oscillatory motion(non-harmonic motion may also mean non-oscillatory motion like linear motion etc..but keeping thing under the topic of oscillation here). They are the type of oscillatory motion in which the restoring force is a non-linear function of displacement i.e. not directly proportional to displacement and the frequency and amplitude may be dependent on each other.

Summary: Oscillation can be put into 2 types: Harmonic and Anharmonic/Non-harmonic. Harmonic motion can be further divided into simple HM and complicated HM.

Is my understanding right?.